# How to properly load textures using the libgdx assetmanager

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Is this how one properly loads a texture into an `AssetManager`?

```
Texture tex;
AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();
manager.load("menu/bg.png",Texture.class);
tex = manager.get("menu/bg.png",Texture.class);
```

The texture fails to load with error "cannot load the texture menu/bg.png".

How should we load our texture using the `AssetManager`?

Answer (score 20):

This is almost how the AssetManager should be used, but not entirely. **I recommend reading on the wiki about the [libgdx AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets).**

Some points:
The variable should be in camelCase, so AssetManager *manager*... instead of AssetManager *Manager*.

You will need to call `manager.update()`; to actually make it load stuff. This will need to be called until `manager.update()`; returns true, then it's done loading. So you can make a loading screen where you call `manager.update();` each frame, and when it returns true you switch to some other screen.
If you just want everything to load, and block until it's loaded, call `manager.finishLoading();` before trying to get anything from the manager.

You may have to create a folder in the `assets` folder named `data` and put your assets there instead of putting them directly in the assets folder. So put your assets in `mygame-android\assets\data` instead of `mygame-android\assets`.

If you're using the gdx-setup-gui to create your project, you should be fine. But if not, your desktop project will need to know where to find the assets as well.

An example on how to create an [animated, responsive loading screen with libgdx](https://github.com/Matsemann/libgdx-loading-screen). ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpI2U_9jDak))

Comment: I am doing the same thing as above, I have seen your video but at this point I just want to use the asset manager just to add a png or a jpg as a background. My code is the same but i have added finishedLoading. and tried to add that to stage but that is not an actor so i can't add it to stage.

manager.load("assets/data/badlogic.jpg",Texture.class);
  manager.finishLoading();
  bg = manager.get("assets/data/badlogic.jpg",Texture.class);
  stage.addActor(bg);

Comment: nb : any directory below assets will do.