# After loading textures application gets short and not controlled freeze

Tags: android, opengl-es, 2d, textures, libgdx

Use libGDX platform. After loading textures my application gets short and not controlled freeze.

```
    @Override
public void render() {
    float deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    if (IS_LOG_ENGINE_SPEED_INFO) {
        startTickCount = System.currentTimeMillis();
        runingAppTime += deltaTime;
    }
    if (sceneDirector.sceneUpdate()) {
        deltaTime = 0;
        if (!manager.update()) {
            Gdx.app.log("aaa", "Skip!");
            return;
        }
    }
    sceneDirector.getCurScene().updateLogic(deltaTime);
    if (IS_LOG_ENGINE_SPEED_INFO) {
        logStr = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTickCount) + ", ";
        startTickCount = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    sceneDirector.getCurScene().updateGraph(batch);

    if (IS_LOG_ENGINE_SPEED_INFO) Gdx.app.log("aaa", logStr + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTickCount));
}
```

What I do: If changed the scene - workout the method sceneDirector.sceneUpdate () and there is a loading of textures. Texture loading function:

```
    public static void loadAtlas(String pngFileName, String xmlFileName, Scene scene) {

    MainClass.manager.load(pngFileName, Texture.class);
    MainClass.manager.finishLoading();
    Texture texture = MainClass.manager.get(pngFileName, Texture.class);
    scene.textures.add(texture);
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    ...
```

And what do we get in the end... Loading methods work out correctly. Rendering graphics is only when the texture loading. This is confirmed by the logs that show the application:

```
01-07 16:38:50.509: INFO/aaa(27259): LogicTime: 1712, GraphTime: 145
01-07 16:38:50.559: INFO/aaa(27259): LogicTime: 0, GraphTime: 38
01-07 16:38:50.559: INFO/aaa(27259): LogicTime: 0, GraphTime: 1
01-07 16:38:50.569: INFO/aaa(27259): LogicTime: 0, GraphTime: 3
01-07 16:38:50.579: INFO/aaa(27259): LogicTime: 1, GraphTime: 1
01-07 16:38:50.589: INFO/aaa(27259): LogicTime: 0, GraphTime: 1
01-07 16:38:50.609: INFO/aaa(27259): LogicTime: 2, GraphTime: 2
01-07 16:38:50.629: INFO/aaa(27259): LogicTime: 0, GraphTime: 1
01-07 16:38:50.649: INFO/aaa(27259): LogicTime: 0, GraphTime: 4
```

But! Why first and second graphics update do so long? This question is important because after loading the graphics immediately begin action on the scene.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
MainClass.manager.finishLoading();
```

is probably where your time is going (though I am not sure because you do not show the `MainClass.manager` definition and you do not show the call graph from `render` to `loadAtlas`). You need to load the assets in the background (see `manager.update()`).  `finishLoading` will block the current thread (render thread) until all assets are loaded.

This means you need to "render" on your render thread before the assets are loaded.  Generally, this is done by displaying a "loading" screen.  See this question: [How to properly load textures using the libgdx assetmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391518/how-to-properly-load-textures-using-the-libgdx-assetmanager)

Comment: in MainClass:
`public static AssetManager manager;
...
    public MainClass() {
        manager = new AssetManager();
    }
`
You are absolutely correct notice. This work in the future will be split into a separate Threat.
But! Now I am concerned about the issue. If we use one process and an additional check in it "!Manager.update ()", why in the next iteration libGDX draws simple sprites for 38 ms?
That is - all atlases are already loaded, but still we do the first drawing of 10-20 times slower than the next.

Comment: Use the profiler to see where the time is going: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html